# iOS Universal link: Keep user in browser even if app is installed

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links, aasa

We have a requirement where we want to keep user in the browser until he completes the onboarding. Is there any way to keep the user in browser even if app is installed.

Issue is once app will come in foreground and then we can manually check and open the same link in browser but in that case app will open and go back to browser will give a bad user experience.

Comment: You can use a WebView in your app and keep that open with onboarding

Comment: No that's not feasible as we do not want user to come from universal links to app until they complete onboarding

Comment: Use a specific path for your onboarding and exclude that path via your Apple app site association file.